# How to set up a storybook environment in preact

Tags: typescript, storybook, preact

I'm setting up a preact development environment.
I use vite for bundler and typescript for application development.

I also want to install storybook(typescript) for testing

After finishing all the installations
When I run storybook, I am getting the following error.
However, I am not able to find the exact cause.

This is how I went about setting up my development environment

1. install preact with vite
   First, I installed preact using the preact cli by referring to the official documentation. (https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started/)
   This process automatically led me to using vite.

```
yarn add preact
```

[image: preact install]

2. install storybook
   https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/preact/get-started/install
   Similarly, I used the official storybook documentation to install storybook, and followed the guide for an environment using storybook 7.0, Preact, and TypeScript.

[image: storybook install]

Then run storybook.
Subsequent runs of storybook open the storybook page, but immediately throw an error and close the window.

Here's the error message

[image: error msg]

I really want to know the cause of the error and how to fix it

Comment: Are you using [the Vite builder](https://storybook.js.org/docs/preact/builders/vite)? You need to in order for Storybook to pick up on the `vite.config.js` that contains Preact-specific configs. Else, you'll need to configure Storybook manually and [set up the React aliases](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#aliasing-react-to-preact).